# NIL representation in PC Scheme TI implementation

Tags: lisp, scheme

I am learning LISP using PC Scheme TI implementation and from the book 'Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs'. PC scheme doesn't seem to have a 'nil' variable

[VM ERROR encountered!] Variable not defined in current environment
NIL

Instead '()' seems to work. 
[55] (define one-through-four (list 1 2 3 4 ()))
ONE-THROUGH-FOUR

Do both have the same meaning? What is the correct way to use a sequence of no elements in the PC scheme dialect?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about PC Scheme but If you want a fully SICP compatible Scheme implementation, you can use [MIT Scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/). Also, I'm not sure if PC Scheme is a `Scheme` since it doesn't have `nil`.

Comment: TI PC Scheme is a very old implementation. Unless you are restricted to an 8088 msdos computer, you'd better switch to a more modern implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say that this dialect "does not have a NIL variable", you are right in two ways. Not only does not `nil` exist, but it seems to be treated as an ordinary symbol that you can use as a variable. It says "Variable not defined".

In Lisp dialects where `nil` has a special meaning, `nil` usually cannot be used as a variable.

`nil` is equivalent to `()` only in "classical" Lisps (my term). By this I mean Lisps that are related by ancestry or imitation to the original John MacCarthy Lisp. Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp are that way. The classical Lisps use `nil` as the list terminator: i.e. `(cons 1 nil)` producing the list `(1)`

Scheme is not a classical Lisp in this sense. There is no `nil`. It uses `()` as the printed notation for an empty list and when you want that value in an expression, it is quoted, just like a non-empty list literal: `'()`. In Scheme, `(cons 1 nil)` is written `(cons 1 '())`. Boolean false is represented by an object which is notated `#f`. An empty list is true not false, so `(if '() 1 2)` yields 1, not 2 like in a classical Lisp. Neither `'()` nor `#f` are symbols.

Scheme is also case-sensitive. Even if you do have a variable `NIL` in Scheme, it has nothing to do with `nil`. You can use both as variable names.

The SICP text causes confusion on this topic by, in its early chapters, making references to a variable called `nil` which holds the value of `'()`.   There is no such variable in Scheme; you have to make it yourself if you want those examples to work. This is an unfortunate aspect of the textbook.

If you define a variable `nil` whose value is the object `'()`, so that that Chapter 2 code from SICP works, it is still not equivalent to an empty list the way it is in a classical Lisp, because in a classical Lisp, `nil` and `()` are equivalent notations for a symbol. The symbol `nil` itself is the empty list, and vice versa. It is not the name of a variable which merely holds a list. And so the quote expression `'nil` also evaluates to the empty list! Whereas in scheme `'nil` evaluates to the ordinary symbol `nil` even if you've defined it as a variable holding the empty list.

Regarding the second question, "() seems to work, do both have the same meaning?". The "same meaning" aspect is covered above: no, not the same meaning in Scheme. As far as it working, consider the following quote from the R5RS Scheme Report:

> Note: In many dialects of Lisp, the empty combination, (), is a legitimate expression. In Scheme, combinations must have at least one subexpression, so () is not a syntactically valid expression. [4.1.3 Procedure Calls]

Therefore this loose treatment of `()` as valid expression that produces the empty list appears to be a PC Scheme extension of behavior, not standard Scheme. It is accepting an expression which is not a syntactically valid Scheme expression.